# Can the Client retrieve it's socket properities?

Tags: web-applications, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io to develop a webapp. I've added some additional properties to the socket on the server side like this,

```
socket.on('foo',function(data){
  socket._foo = "hello";
});
```

On the client side javascript can I retrieve the '._foo' property? or will I have to send that data via an emit on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That property will only be stored in the servers memory for that socket session, it will not be available on the client side. You would need to emit back to the client.

Comment: Gotcha, that's what I thought. Thank you.